# php input validation check and simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, simplexml

```
if(isset(file_get_contents("php://input"))) {
        $credentialsXML = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("php://input"));
}
```

how can we check if php://input exists and then go ahead with parsing, as there are cases where php://input would be empty, and I simply don't need to call simplexml_load_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
if (!empty($input)) {
    $credentialsXML = simplexml_load_string($input);
}
```